# Tick Marks on a Grid

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to put tick marks on this tikzpicture, I have not used the axis environment. I have a lot of these graphs to draw for my students. This one needed to be x = 2cm y = 1cm grid. I have done this, but is there just a quicker way of drawing this? Also, I'd like a faster way of drawing  the first quadrant, second quadrant and all four quadrants for students to draw lines on. Sometime s the graph has to be small on the page, and sometimes to be width of the page is there a quicker way of doing this?

Here's my MWE

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}


\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    


\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray,very thin, step=1cm, yscale=0.5, xscale=1,scale=2, ] (-1,-1) grid (7,10);    
        \draw[line width=0.5mm, <->] (-1,0) -- (14.5,0);
        \draw[line width=0.5mm,  <->] (0,-1) -- (0,10.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use `yscale=0.5, xscale=1, scale=2` insteas of `yscale=1, xscale=2` which produces the same result and where the values of the scaling are conform your `x=2cm / y=1cm` request?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I wanted a grid composed of rectangles 2cm long (x-axis) and 1cm high y axis, and I couldn't find anything on the website, so I just played with it and achieved it by the above code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[gray!15,step=1cm] (-8,-8) grid (8,8);    
            \draw[line width=0.5mm, -latex] (-8,0) -- (8.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
            \foreach \x in {-8,...,8} \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
            \draw[line width=0.5mm,  -latex] (0,-8) -- (0,8.2) node[above] {$y$};
            \foreach \y in {-8,...,8} \draw (.1,\y)--(-.1,\y) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
            \draw[red] plot[domain= -8:8] (\x,{.5*\x-2});
            \draw[blue] plot[domain= -8:8] (\x,{-.7*\x+1});
            \draw[cyan,line width=2pt] plot[domain= -5.5:5.5] (\x,{.4*\x*\x-4});
        \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```